# What is the meaning of (^| )ABC( |$) as an extended REGEX ?

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

I came here across the command **grep -E '(^| )ABC( |$)' file1**
I am confused how to interpret the regular expression therein, because I know the ^ and $ character as beginning and end signifier, but in here they are not at the very beginning or end because of the bracket, ^ is sometimes used to negate a set of character, but I have seen this usage only in [^....] like expression.

Could someone explain step by step the meaning of this regex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that `grep` should search for `ABC` string only at the beginning of the line *OR* after space, moreover this string has to end with another space OR the end of the line.

In other words someone wanted to search for a strings which form whole *words*. However this regexp has many issues, namely there could be many other characters before and after *word* (at least in natural language), i.e. `(`,`)`,`.`,`;`,`:`,`,`,`...`, etc.

Thus, it is better to use `-w` option of `grep`, alternatively play with boundaries: `\b` or `\<`/`\>`.

Comment: Not all implementations of `grep` have `-w`, `\b` or `\<`, none of which are standard. The GNU one doesn't work with multibyte locales (`echo épris | grep -w pris` matches).